# Error: fs.readFileSync is not a function using Electron

Tags: electron, pdfkit

I’m having problems using pdfkit in Electron due to “fs.readFileSync is not a function” … how can i use fs library in Electron? I’ve read that is disabled for security reasons, but i would need it to be executed offline.

Comment: "I’ve read that is disabled for security reasons" where?

Answer (score 1):

In Electron Framework as we know we have two type of process .

> 1.) Main Process
>
> 2.)Render Process

so main.js file which you passed to command `electron main.js` (Note:- while you are calling it with command line arguments ) so at this time electron will create 2 process . one is main process in which your `main.js` run and from that process it will launch your `index.html` file and scripts which you include in it in another render process.

so in that main.js file use the fs module like we do in the node.js using

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync()
```

and the data you get it here pass to the render process using interprocess communication provided by the `Electron Framework` using its APIs `IPCRender IPCMain`.

Comment: you can also just simply `require` module in renderer process.

Comment: @pergy can you? I see it mentioned frequently but haven't really seen anyone do it.

Comment: Actually I just tried and - yes you can! Huh... nut only if you have `nodeIntegration` set to `true`.